# SQL Agent job failed

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I am creating job in SQL Agent, which will execute one TSQL Batch for shrink log file.

A also create schedule to run this job every month. After initial successful testing, I just wanted to see TSQL batch again, double click on job, choose Steps, and click on Edit step, but then I got an error:

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {some guid} 
from the IClassFactory failed due to the 
following error: c001f011 (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, in fact, in missing some fixes to service packs.

Here is explanation:

[FIX](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2315727)